# How to use $refs in vue child component to shift focus?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using this code to shift focus between text inputs in a `v-for` list:

HTML

```
<input :ref="'inputField' + index" @keydown.down="movedown(index)" type="text"
enter code here`v-model="todo.text">
```

JS

```
movedown: function(index){
 this.$nextTick(() =>
    this.$refs["inputField" + (1 + index)][0].focus()
  );
}
```

It works fine when the input-fields are in the same component as the v-for. However, when I move the input-fields and the code to a child component I instead get an error that "*this.$refs[("inputField" + (1 + index))] is undefined*".

Here is a working JSFiddle where you can move down inputs with down-arrow: https://jsfiddle.net/Gnopps/w5xqa1r9/

Here is the same code, but in a child component and you can no longer move down: https://jsfiddle.net/Gnopps/y17en6o4/

Would anyone have any idea how I can fix this so that I can shift focus also with the input-fields in a child component?

Comment: You can try something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/mxc8jz2n/1/). When you press down, component will emit event to parent, and parent will focus next component.

Comment: You're getting that error because components don't all share the same `$refs` object. They each have their own `$refs` object which is populated by whatever you tag in their template with the `ref` attribute. So you pass `0` as the `index` prop to that first child component and then when the `movedown` method fires it's trying to access `this.$refs["inputField1"][0]`, which doesn't exist because the only ref you've defined for that component is `this.$refs["inputField0"]`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @ljubadr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ljubadr's answer in the comments worked perferctly. Basically move ref to parent and then `this.$refs["inputField" + (1 + index)][0].$el.focus()`:

You can try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mxc8jz2n/1/). When you press down, component will emit event to parent, and parent will focus next component

Comment: Gnopps you can post the answer from the link that I provided, I don't mind. I don't have time to create the answer